Arrange $1,1,2,2,\ldots,n,n$ on a line such that there are $k$ numbers between two $k$s
Find all positive integers $n$ with the following property. It is possible to place $2n$ numbers on a row from left to right, such that for any $1\leq k\leq n$, $k$ appears exactly twice and there are exactly $k$ numbers between the two $k$s.
For example, $n=3$ has the property as shown by $2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3$.

An easy parity argument shows $n\equiv 0\text{ or }3\mod 4$. Do examples exist for all such $n$?
This is an old problem if my memory is good, but I cannot find a source. I have googled things like n numbers between two ns, but found nothing. Curious anyone knows the “history” of the problem?
Is this a standalone problem or a special case of research mathematics (e.g. combinatorial design)?

Thank you.
Update: After this is posted @MJD made me aware of a similar question. The problems are slightly different in that the linked question requires there are $k-1$ numbers (as opposed to $k$ numbers) between two $k$s; per Langford pairing, they are Skolem sequences and has applications in e.g. combinatorial design. The answers in the linked question only shows necessary condition (parity argument) but not constructions (which is probably not an easy task given it is content of published papers, see the references in the aforementioned article); it also has no discussion of the history of the problem.

these are called langord sequences

Thank you @DannyBlozrov!

This question is similar to: Is it possible to arrange the integers $1, 1, 2, 2,..., 1998, 1998$ such that there are exactly $i − 1$ other numbers between any two $i$'s?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you @MJD. I’ve edited as requested.
